# How to use elasticsearch library on python with elastic cloud?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

Newbie to Rest API and elastic cloud here trying to post my json file in the elasticsearch so I can then index and see it in the kibana. So I read online of the library of elasticsearch and I followed its example basically to the [letter.](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2015/02/17/python-elasticsearch-first-steps/) But yet I am getting a connection error when I try and run the thing. Now, the tutorial is refering to on-prem elastic and not cloud so I am guessing the authentication isn't the same for cloud and I should add the user and password somehow to this? Can anyone help me with that?

Do note,  when I try to use get I actually get the code 200 so communications should be fine

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'https:/cloudhosturl', 'port': 9243}])
    for i,line in enumerate(emails):
        for match in re.finditer(from_pat, line):
            ioc.append(match.group(1))
            es.index(index='senders', doc_type='addresses', id=k, body=json.dumps(match.group(1)))
```

> elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   ConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001]
>   getaddrinfo failed) caused by:
>   NewConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001]
>   getaddrinfo failed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the snippet from https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/ it works for elastic cloud cluster.
It requires `pip install elasticsearch`

example:

```
es = Elasticsearch(
['https:/cloudhosturl'],
http_auth=('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'),
scheme="https", port=443,)
```